# I can use org.reflection to get package classes using wildcard?

Tags: java, reflection, reflections

I was using

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.mypackage.root", new MethodAnnotationsScanner());
```

But with this aproach i get back a lot of annotations in packages level that i don't need...
What i really want for, is something like this, using an wildcard to get back the deep package level only.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.mypackage.root.*.deep", new MethodAnnotationsScanner())
```

Because the methods that i really need is in ".deep" package level... I try a lot of combinations with FilterBuilder, then i don't know if i am doing something wrong or this is not possible with this API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.mypackage.root", new MethodAnnotationsScanner());

Set<Method> methods = reflections
        .getMethodsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class).stream()
        .filter(method -> method.getDeclaringClass().getPackage().getName().matches("com.mypackage.root.*.deep"))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working fine for me.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("com.package.root"))
                    .setScanners(new MethodAnnotationsScanner()));
    
Set<Method> methods = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(MyRequestMapping.class);
```

I used the `org.reflections` dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```